# problems with php POST - POST body is empty in login request

Tags: php, json, post, request, postman

I am currently working on an APP that sends a post request to a server to login. The backend developer of my team is a bit slow so I thought why wouldn't I just set up some mock urls for testing the app.
 I got a php file for the login which should return me a session when I enter correct data. Unfortunately I am stuck trying to get the JSON i post into some variables.

In fact, i don't see any data i receive. I've tried to use vardump on `$_POST`, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as wel as `file_get_contents("php://input")`. I tried to decode the latter two with `json_decode`.
 Some give me `String(0) ""` others give me `NULL`. In some cases i just got nothing.

Using retrofit i send a request to **/login** with a body of

```
{
    "password":"password",
    "username":"Marcel"
 }
```

However when what i get as return is nothing. The my php code is only getting the and returning a json object with a session token

```
if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])){
    $id= array('SESSION_ID' => 'random_session_token_0015');
    echo json_encode($id);
}
```

This code example does not give me any return. Using `print_r($_POST);` i will get an empty array like `array()`.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$object = json_decode($json);
var_dump($object);
```

This code example does give me any return, but it is **NULL**. `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` had the same result as the latter example.

I'm quite stuck in this problem, anyone there to help?

ps. aks if you need more info

[image: Postman interface]

Comment: @mikeb what should i do beter in your opinion

Comment: I see your edit.  What happens if you put some debug statements, such as `print_r($_POST)` above your `if...` stuff and verify that your data is actually there...  A good question should post your code (we can't see your request code), your output that you are getting and what you expect at the very least.

Comment: @mikeb the `print_r($_POST);` will show `Array()`

Comment: Well, your if is never going to work if you are not posting the data properly.

Comment: Did you solve this? How?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the same problem by making sure I send the `"Content-Type: application/json"` header to my Node.js server.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  In my case, the request was being made using http as the protocol, however an Apache redirect to https was causing the request body to be lost in the process of that redirect.  Using the correct protocol and avoiding that redirect fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
file_get_contents(
    'php://input', 
    false, 
    stream_context_get_default(), 
    0, 
    $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']
);
```

Comment: I don't get why somebody gave me -1.. no comment. More - that is only code which worked for me